# Extract Some bytes from .bin file with Python

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bpN8.png)I'm trying to extract specific block of bytes in Python (I already know the size)  but I want Python to take the size of bytes from the file witch written in some where  ,
I can seek to the position and print out the size , but Python always tell me this is 'str' the value must be an integer . I converted 'str' to 'int' but same error message!
this is an image just I uploaded, I don't want to write the size in the code I want Python go to this position and take this number as size, because I'm writing a simple app to extract .Zlip from .bin files and need the app to automatically take the size itself from this offset, I just started with Python One month ago.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you actually tried ... but this should work fine

```
OFFSET_BYTES = 100
PAYLOAD_SIZE = 20
with open("myfile.bin","rb") as f:
     f.seek(OFFSET_BYTES)
     payload = f.read(PAYLOAD_SIZE)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response I'll try it now